# postfix can't send mail on debian 7 server

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, postfix-mta, debian-7.6.0

I've set up a simple postfix/doecot on my Debian 7 server to send and receive some mails.
receiving emails works good but i can't send any mail. My Outlook says that he can't connect to the server. 
I tried almost anything i found on the internet but nothing helped me out. I hope some one here can find my mistake and helps me to fix the problem.

If i try '*telnet mail.mydomain.de 25*' it stucks with a timeout.

```
telnet mail.mydomain.de 25
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xx...
Connected to mail.mydomain.de.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.mydomain.de ESMTP
421 4.4.2 mail.mydomain.de Error: timeout exceeded
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The same result with Port 587 and 8080

This is my **main.cf:**

```
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

##SASL##

#smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

##TLS##

smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no 
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/apache2/SSLcerts/www_domain_de.crt  
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/apache2/SSLcerts/domain.key 
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.mydomain.de
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydomain = mydomain.de
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = localhost, $mydomain
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_transport = virtual
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 0
mailbox_size_limit = 0

##restrictions##

#smtpd_helo_required=yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes

##limit rate##
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 5
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 5

smtpd_error_sleep_time = 5s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 2
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 3
##################

smtpd_helo_restrictions= reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
  reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
  reject_unknown_helo_hostname

smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unknown_client_hostname,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org

smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  reject_unknown_sender_domain

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_invalid_hostname,
  reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
  reject_unauth_destination,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
  reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
  reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
  reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net

smtpd_recipient_limit = 250
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

#message_size_limit = 120480000

##remove IP header##
# requires postfix-pcre (apt-get install postfix-pcre)
#header_checks has the following content:
#/^\s*(Received: from)[^\n]*(.*)/ REPLACE $1 [127.0.0.1] (localhost [127.0.0.1])$2
#
#smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

And here is the **master.cf**

```
    smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
8080      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

I really hope that some one find the issue cause i need this mailserver.

Comment: Ist there no one who can help me? ...please....

Answer (score 0):

Right now it looks like only the server can send email, try adding your ip subnet to "mynetworks"

Also the output of the maillog would help.